# Woman loses her memory in the end

Tags: identify-this-movie

Unfortunately, I don't remember much about the movie.

It was sort of about a man and a woman getting or being together. And in the end the woman lost her memory somehow. (maybe even by him? Or on her own behalf?) One of the last scenes shows her randomly walking by the man on the street but she doesn't even recognize him. He does recognize her but decided that it was better to leave it at that; I don't remember why. I also don't remember how the memory loss actually happened.

I watched it like ~10 years ago in German TV, however it looked like an American production.

I believe that he knew or even caused the memory loss on her because he knew it was better for her; even if she wouldn't even know him anymore after that.

Maybe she had memories of some kind that really screwed her up and it was so bad, that in the end he decided to get her memory erased, even if that means losing her, but she would feel better.

As far as I remember the movie had a really great story and I wish that I could find and watch it again.

Comment: [Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338013/?ref_=nv_sr_1) - you might want to check this. Sounds a little similar. Or at least a good watch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put it on my watch list! The one I was looking for seems to be The Butterfly Effect though :)

Comment: @Paharet, apart from the memory loss thing, this doesn't at all sound anything like ESotSM.

Comment: @Octupus 8 - No, it does not. But this is identify-this-movie and when one saw movie 10+ years ago, he/she tends to build up on vague memory. People do that unintentionally - they remember things that they coined up years ago and repeated till it become their "memory".  I am just trying to help. Relationship drama and loss of memory were the keywords I took into consideration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might be looking for [The Butterfly Effect](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289879/) from 2004 starring Ashton Kutcher and Amy Smart.

It is actually a movie about time travel.

Here the plot from wikipedia explaining her memory "loss":

> Growing up, Evan Treborn and his friends, Lenny and siblings Kayleigh and Tommy Miller, suffered many severe psychological traumas that frequently caused Evan to black out. [...]
>
> Seven years later, [...] Evan discovers that when he reads from his adolescent journals, he can travel back in time and redo parts of his past. [...] there are consequences to his revised choices that dramatically alter his present life. [...] Eventually, he realizes that, even though his intentions to fix the past are good, his actions have unforeseen consequences, in which either he or at least one of his friends does not benefit.[...] **He ultimately reaches the conclusion that he and his friends might not have good futures as long as he keeps altering the past, and he realizes that he is hurting them rather than helping.**
>
> Evan travels back one final time to the day he first met Kayleigh as a child. He intentionally upsets her so that she and Tommy will choose to live with their mother, in a different neighborhood, instead of with their father when they divorce.[...]
>
> Eight years later in New York City, an adult Evan exits an office building and passes by Kayleigh on the street. Though a brief look of recognition passes over both of their faces, **they both decide to keep walking.**

There are different endings, and the first one in that video corresponds to what you described (it also include the part where he upset the girl):

Comment: One of the scenes in that youtube compilation looks like that could be it! I'll watch the movie and let you know if this is really it. Thanks a ton so far!

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy the watch, I will advise you to check the director cut (with the last ending), it's not a happy ending, but that's also why it could be considered better or at least unique.

Comment: Yeah it definitely is butterfly effect, and I'd also go for the director's cut ending. Much better than the ending you recall.

Comment: Knew it was it by his description. I LOVE this movie from the beginning to the end.

Comment: Just finished watching it. Surprisingly I barely remembered/recognized anything from the movie except the last few minutes. But yeah, this is definitely the movie I was looking for :) I didn't watch the Director's Cut version right away, but I watched the 'normal' version and followed up with the ending compilation you linked. I'm personally not sure if I like the Theatrical or Director Cut ending better -- I love them both. And I love the movie. Thank you so much for bringing this back to me <3